# Elisp: sorting SYM VAL pairs in a setq expression

Tags: sorting

I wrote a rather clunky elisp function to sort the *SYM* *VAL* args in a *setq* expression alphabetically by *SYM*. For example:

```
(setq c "blah"              (setq a 9
      b '(more stuff)  -->        b '(more stuff)
      a 9)                        c "blah")
```

After reading about *sort-subr*, I thought I might be able to build a cleaner implementation. I thought I had it, but something's not right. What am I doing wrong here?

```
(defun sort-setq ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (let ((sort-end (progn (end-of-defun)
                             (backward-char)
                             (point-marker)))
            (sort-beg (progn (beginning-of-defun)
                             (re-search-forward "[ \\t]*(" (point-at-eol))
                             (forward-sexp)
                             (re-search-forward "\\<" (point-at-eol))
                             (point-marker))))
        (narrow-to-region (1- sort-beg) (1+ sort-end))
        (sort-subr nil #'sort-setq-next-record #'sort-setq-end-record)))))

(defun sort-setq-next-record ()
  (condition-case nil
      (progn
        (forward-sexp 3)
        (backward-sexp))
    ('scan-error (end-of-buffer))))

(defun sort-setq-end-record ()
  (condition-case nil
      (forward-sexp 2)
    ('scan-error (end-of-buffer))))
```

It seems to work for the 3-pair example above, but if I start adding more pairs it fails to sort them all.

Comment: (I wonder why you want to do this.)

Comment: @Drew It's partly just me messing around and getting familiar with elisp, but also there are some groups of variables in my init file that are "miscellaneous" (I can't find any other way to organize them that makes sense) and it makes it easier to find them visually if I keep them alphabetized.

Answer (score 1):

If each `SYM VAL` is one the same line, you can simply use `M-x sort-lines`. For your example,

```
(setq c "blah"
      b '(more stuff)
      a 9)

-->

(setq
 c "blah"
 b '(more stuff)
 a 9
 ) 

M-x sort-lines -->

(setq
 a 9
 b '(more stuff)
 c "blah"
 )

-->

(setq a 9
      b '(more stuff)
      c "blah")
```

Answer (score 0):

In `sort-setq-next-record` you where jumping to far. Instead of using `(forward-sexp 3)` you should use `(forward-sexp 1)`.

Here is the new function:

```
(defun sort-setq-next-record ()
    (condition-case nil
            (progn
                (forward-sexp 1)
                (backward-sexp))
        ('scan-error (end-of-buffer))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt

```elisp
(defun sort-setq (beg end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region beg end)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((nextrecfun (lambda () (skip-chars-forward " \n")))
          (endrecfun  (lambda () (forward-sexp 2))))
      (sort-subr nil nextrecfun endrecfun))))
```

Note that you need to select just SYM-VAL pairs to the Region, e.g., to sort `(setq b 2 a 1)`, select `b 2 a 1`.